# Are some CG/Gameplay removed from Mugen Souls during Localization

Tags: mugen-souls

i was google searching images and i saw some 2 kinds of screenshots,

- one was of the Heroines, Sunny (she's the only one who could be classed as a Demon Lord) and Chou Chous Personalities covered in soap in provocative poses (i don't remember seeing one of Atlas)
- The other was Atlas in a steamed filled room and you was apparently massaging her, the image linked to a youtube video of the player using certain items when using the hotspring to trigger this mini game

Now i never had any need to use the hotsprings and i haven't done any Post Came Content, the images (and video) all showed the game in Japanese and i have both the US and PAL versions of the game but i only played the PAL version.

I am wondering if during the localization if anything was removed?

i know this has happened before as in Agarest Generations of War 2 when it was localized for PAL, the Young Fiona Bathouse Minigames was removed and when i contacted Ghostlight about the missing Ellis DLC i got a reply saying it was not made available because it apparently added young Ellis who also had Bathouse Minigames (i got the other 3 characters and neither one of women added had minigames so it makes me wonder why only young Ellis would be the only DLC to add them)

Comment: I know it has been confirmed that localizations of the sequel will have bathhouse fun removed so I am confident the original had this kind of censorship as well. I'll get a source for you on that.

Comment: @skovacs1 will that be just for the US Localization or for both US and PAL versions

Comment: I've got the source. Writing up an answer. In the source, they clarify that all of their localizations got the same treatment and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to [NISA's official forums](http://nisamerica.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=9704), the only significant edit was the removal of the bath mini games:

> The Japanese version of the game contained a mini-game in which the player had to scrub/grope 2D depictions of female characters in a variety of bath scenes. The characters and surrounding audio/visual elements were extremely sexualized, and a number of the characters were depicted as potentially being pubescent or pre-pubescent. We decided to remove this content out of concern for the potential of receiving an AO rating from the ESRB, which would prevent us from releasing the game. In addition, as a company, we did not want NISA to release or be known for content that could be seen as sexualizing or objectifying children in this way. As this system contained no real story elements or gameplay (it was used to level up your characters, but the player's inputs had no impact on the final stats) we felt it was not a substantial loss of content. Note that your characters will still level up as if you had viewed the scenes, so no gameplay functionality is lost.

This is the same for all territories.

> Our decision wasn't based on the reception in any one particular region. It was a sum-total decision based on a variety of factors. Time and resources has made it unfeasible to release multiple versions of the game across different regions.

They cannot release DLC with rating-affecting content because it would have to be rated and could change the game's base rating:

> If you release DLC that has material that is potentially "more pertinent" to the ESRB (i.e. objectionable) then that DLC has to be submitted for rating, and it can potentially change the rating of the game itself. In this case, we would be facing the same issue as we faced in the beginning. So this isn't an option. For the same reasons, we are also unable to release another version with all the content.

Other than that, they did some minor contextual dialogue edits to make them fit more in-line with the tone and may have toned down Sadie a bit (she's a little more extreme and blunt in the Japanese delivery), but not in any way that loses meaning or affects the narrative.